# Is there way to have a variable of a printed output of a php file, in php?

Tags: php

Is there way to have a variable of a printed output of a php file, in php?

If I use `$userfile = file_get_contents("users.php");` the `$userfile` variable will have php code in it. Is there a way to do this, but `$userfile` only contains the output of the file?

Comment: This is PHP evaluation. Use `include` instead.

Comment: `$userfile = include("users.php");` but return from `users.php` not echo etc.

Comment: use of php function.

Comment: Whats in `users.php`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone https://gist.github.com/desbest/92293164fae38206fcb9f32186478a08

Comment: change `echo` to `return`..

Comment: @tilz0R `include` doesn't work.

Comment: I got it working. Thank you lot for your help.

Answer (score -2):

use `require_once("users.php");`
then you can use the code in the file.